# Naming Action<T> arguments? (single-value tuples?)

Tags: c#, callback, tuples

So, if I have more than one parameter that I want to include in my callback, I can use a value tuple to give them names (for context), while still using the generic Action<T> delegate.

Like so:

```
public async void WaitUntilAbleToGetValue(Action<(float value, float timeSpentWaiting)> then)
{
    // await something that takes a while, keep track of time spent waiting
    // get value
           
    then?.Invoke((value: myValue, timeSpentWaiting: myTimeElapsed));
}
```

This is great because it allows us to add context to these action arguments in a very shorthand way. No need to declare a custom delegate or a struct type... It's all right there.

So I tried to do the same for a single parameter... And I get error [CS8124](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs8124) saying a tuple must have at least two elements... So `Action<(T myValue)>` just doesn't work apparently... which is a real shame.

(for reference, this is C# 9 iirc.. It's the one Unity 2021 uses)

So I wanted to ask here, if anybody knows ways to name a call back argument like this, without having to go through the trouble of declaring a custom delegate type and all that.

And yes, I am being lazy. Yes I am looking for that sweet syntax sugar.

Thanks in advance!

Cheers

Comment: I'd just declare my own delegate type. Then you can put the names on the arguments themselves and you don't have to use tuples.

Comment: "_without having to go through the trouble of declaring a custom delegate type and all that_" It's one line to do that, and gives you exactly wat you want. The tuple version is just as verbose, and looks odd when the delegate is invoked.

Comment: Yes it might be just one line, but using value tuples requires zero new declarations.

Also declared delegates have their own problems as well... I can rant about that anytime.